# Relay fragment not returning mocked data in test

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, relayjs, relay

I'm trying to unit test this component (which uses a Relay JS fragment):

```
const Row = (me) => {
  const {name, email} = useFragment(RowFragment, me)

  return ...
}

const RowFragment = graphql`
    fragment RowFragment_me on User {
        email
        name
    }
`
```

To test it, I've wrapped it in a QueryRenderer with a mocked environment - similarly to how the [docs](https://relay.dev/docs/v11.0.0/guides/testing-relay-components/#fragment-component-tests) suggest. Here is the contents on my test:

```
it('should mock response and render component', () => {
       const environment = createMockEnvironment()

       const TestComponent = props => {
            return (
                <Row me={props.viewer.me} />
            )
        }

        const renderer = render(
           <RelayEnvironmentProvider environment={environment}>
              <QueryRenderer
               environment={environment}
               query={TestQuery}
               render={({ props }) => {
                 if (props) return <TestComponent {...props} />
                 return <div>Loading...</div>
               }}
               variables={variables}
              />
           </RelayEnvironmentProvider>
        )

     act(() => {
            environment.mock.resolveMostRecentOperation(operation =>
                MockPayloadGenerator.generate(operation)
            )
        })
}
```

The line `const {name, email} = useFragment(RowFragment, me)` now fails because the response from useFragment is undefined. I can see that `me` is correctly passed into the component.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of Relay are you using, the linked docs is pointing to `v11.0.0` it doesn't seem to he using `<QueryRenderer>` like this. I assume you're using Relay classic?

Comment: Shouldn't `const RowFragment` be declared before it is used? In the posted example it comes afterwards